# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. IIS 10 New Publish POST API

Tags: web-services, publish, http-status-code-401, iis-10

I Have ASP.NET Web API2 Web service , I am trying to Publish it in new server IIS 10 ,
But it's return 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials with it's web page.
when I request POST Method ,
I tried it locally and its work fine and it was worked perfect in old server  .
can anyone suggest any solution ?

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of authentication module of Web API on IIS and the security of folder. It seems that you didnot give the permission of anonymous users to read the content of application's folder.

Comment: By the way, did you set the permission of application's folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had to Disable Basic authentication while anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS .